# Controlling openvpn auth-user-pass in ifup scripts?

Tags: debian, openvpn

I have the following configured in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
 iface companyvpn inet manual
 openvpn company
```

This allows me to:

```
 ifup companyvpn
```

But unfortunately I am unable to provide my credentials as it appears to stop/place the process in the background?

```
 ifup companyvpn 
 Starting virtual private network daemon: companyEnter Auth Username:
 [1]+  Stopped                 ifup companyvpn
```

Any ideas how to allow the acceptance of username and password at the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by supplying my user credentials directly.

The line in `/etc/openvpn/client.conf`:

```
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/client.cred
```

The file takes the format of:

```
someusername
somepassword
```

Make sure you watch the file permissions though! `600` should be adequate.

Ran `ifup` and everything worked:

```
ifup companyvpn
Starting virtual private network daemon: company.
```

Comment: Just a side note, it seems there is no easy way to encrypt this auth file. Worth looking into though.

Comment: I realize this is old, but the reason there isn't a way to encrypt it is because then you'd need to ask for a passphrase to decrypt it. Which wouldn't work. You can, of course, use full-disk encryption, then it will be encrypted.